# Пробую создать программу с использованием opengl библиотеки в Qt Creator-e

Tags: qt, qt5, opengl

В общем создал проект консольный в нём подключил opengl (не знал особо как пихнул как в CONFIG так и QT)

**файл.про**

```
    QT -= gui
    QT += opengl
    CONFIG += c++11 console opengl
    CONFIG -= app_bundle

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

    SOURCES += main.cpp

    LIBS += -lOpengl32 \
```

**файл.спп**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void)
{
/*  clear all pixels  */
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/*  draw white polygon (rectangle) with corners at
 *  (0.25, 0.25, 0.0) and (0.75, 0.75, 0.0)
 */
    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f (0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f (0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f (0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
        glVertex3f (0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();

/*  don't wait!
 *  start processing buffered OpenGL routines
 */
    glFlush ();
}

void init (void)
{
/*  select clearing (background) color       */
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

/*  initialize viewing values  */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

/*
 *  Declare initial window size, position, and display mode
 *  (single buffer and RGBA).  Open window with "hello"
 *  in its title bar.  Call initialization routines.
 *  Register callback function to display graphics.
 *  Enter main loop and process events.
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (250, 250);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("hello");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Выдаёт ошибки "не видит связей". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Воспользовался вариантом @KoVadim -a.
 Попробовал подключить **только** `LIBS += -lglut` но показала те же ошибки как на картинке (.png).

Потом [скачал саму библиотеку](https://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) и напрямую подключил. НО написала дофига ошибок.

Как я заметил, эта проблема возможно связанна с тем фактом что у меня 64-ричная система, а компилятор мигвей 32-ричный .

Лучший результат :

```
LIBS +=  -lglut \
#        -lglut32 \
        -lOpengl32 \
```

Вы водит две ошибки :

```
ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'  
ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я поменял последнюю строку pro файла на такую

```
LIBS += -lglut
```

и все скомпилилось.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, по сути помогло , но у вы полностью от ошибок не избавило.

Comment: ну так перейдите на 64битный компилятор

Comment: Не могу ;_;  это компилятор из коробки, а другие весьма не явные и надо устанавливать микрософт визуал студию а она весьма не проста

Comment: Посоветуй те пожалуйста  64битный компилятор чтоб можно было легко установить (желательно с комментариями как установить "дорожной картой")

Comment: возможно мой способ покажется странным, но тогда Вам проще запустить виртуалку с линуксом.

Comment: Я пошёл некоторым другим путём. Попробую через visual studio. Не знаю каков будет результат (думаю печальный ).

Answer (score 0):

В общем удалось решить через QtCreator (по правде говоря с glut-ом даже легче запустилось)

Скачанные архивы glew-2.1.0-win32.zip и glfw  кладём в папку проекта.
Я их для удобства переименовал glew_bin и glfw_bin.

Добавил от туда библиотеки и заголовочные файлы . 
Добавлял библиотеки через интерфейс пользователя.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снимем фсе :3 галочки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подключаем библиотеку лежащую (МИНГВЕЕЕ)(у меня сборщик из коробки Qt5.10.1) в C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a**

***ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО НАДО ПОДКЛЮЧИТЬ !!!!*** **libgdi32.a**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем основные сложности прошли (добавлял заголовочные файлы через "Добавить существующие файлы...") и для удобства прописываем  INCLUDEPATH(чтоб при подключении полный путь не прописывать).

---

Еще в самом коде надо подключать заголовочном файлы в таком порядке :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio> // обязательно подключаем для инициализации GLchar и других опенГЛовских переменных

#include <glew.h> //глев подключ раньше ост опенГЛовских библиотек
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
```

С начало  cstdio --> glew --> gl ---> glfw3 .

Только так один за другим (как чёрт за мужиком :3) иначе будет ругаться.

---

***Вот КОД :***

**experiment.pro**

```
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

QT += opengl
LIBS += -lopengl32

SOURCES += main.cpp
#-
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/include/GLFW/ # добавляем для удобства чтоб напрямую писать
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glew_bin/include/GL/   # только название заголовчного файла без полного пути

HEADERS += \
    glfw_bin/include/GLFW/glfw3.h \
    glfw_bin/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h \
    glew_bin/include/GL/glew.h

#-
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/glfw_bin/lib-mingw/ -lglfw3

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/lib-mingw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/lib-mingw

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/glfw_bin/lib-mingw/ -lglfw3dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/lib-mingw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/lib-mingw
#-- тут попытка
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/glew_bin/lib/Release/Win32/ -lglew32

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glew_bin/lib/Release/Win32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/glew_bin/lib/Release/Win32

#-  дошло до смешного надо из компилятора библиотеки подтягивать а то он не справляется :3
win32: LIBS += -LC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -lgdi32
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include
DEPENDPATH += C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include
#--#
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio> // обязательно подключаем для инициализации GLchar и других опенГЛовских переменных

#include <glew.h> //глев подключ раньше ост опенГЛовских библиотек
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <glfw3.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC


const char * APP_TITLE = "Introduction to Modern OpenGL - Hello Windows 1";
const int gWindowWidth = 800;
const int gWindowHeight = 600;

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) // если глф инит не инициализированно то сюда не зайдет (проверка на подключение библиотек)
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed" << std::endl;
        return -1; // я как понял  прерывает прогу из за того что ретюрн -1 это по сути команда прекращения работы проги
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow * pWindow = glfwCreateWindow(gWindowWidth, gWindowHeight, APP_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if (pWindow == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Falled to create GLFW window " << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate(); // ? не совсем понятно что она делает
        return -1; // команда прекращения работты проги
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(pWindow); // тоже почитай

    // glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; .// заблочил в связи того что он давал ошибку: "не инициализированная переменная " хотя
    // glewExperimental относиться к GLEWAPI (переменная апишника) странно :/
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) // если инициализалция не ок, то предупреждение и поджопник
    {
        std::cerr << "GLEW initialization falied" << std::endl;
        return -1; // команда прекращения работы проги
    }
    // main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(pWindow))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(pWindow);
    }

    glfwTerminate();  
    return 0;
}
```

---

***Ух фсе :3***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот ещё один вариант :

**.proфайл не меняем!!!**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>

#include "glfw3.h"
#include "glfw3native.h"

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

***Прекрасно отработал :3***